Can ANY_VALUE(ORDER BY) be an agg version of FIRST_VALUE?
I always need to do something like this to get the i.e. First customer by country from a customers table. Always wondered if there was a shorter way.
SELECT
    country,
    MAX(first_customer) AS first_customer
FROM (
    SELECT
        country
        ,FIRST_VALUE(customer) OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY inserted_date) AS first_customer
    FROM customers
) x
GROUP BY 1;

I've been playing around with the recently added ANY_VALUE function and it seems that it can give the same result?
SELECT
    country
    ,ANY_VALUE(customer ORDER BY inserted_date) AS first_customer
FROM customers
GROUP BY 1;

I'm not well educated on how ORDER BY within agg functions works, so I'm not sure if the output is reliable, some tests I did were positive though.
This would be huge as I could combine this with a i.e. FILTER(WHERE age > 30) without that much of code.
I'm not considering any null/not-null values as ANY_VALUE ignores nulls. (Thanks for the clarification @Adrian Klaver)


Read Aggregate expressions for information on what is going on. Short version The order_by_clause has the same syntax as for a query-level ORDER BY clause, as described in Section 7.5, except that its expressions are always just expressions and cannot be output-column names or numbers. 2) More to the point any_value ignores NULL values.


I've run multiple experiments using ANY_VALUE(... ORDER BY ...) and it seems to consistently return the first value based on the ORDER BY expression; however, I would be hesitant to rely on this behavior, especially since it runs counter to the function's description. In the PostgreSQL documentation, section 9.21. Aggregate Functions, the description of ANY_VALUE is:

any_value ( anyelement ) → same as input type  
    Returns an arbitrary value from the non-null input values.


The concept of order is logically inconsistent with the concept of selecting an arbitrary value. I suspect that the observed behavior is an incidental result of using common code to handle aggregate functions and not a deliberate feature. The lack of regression tests in the PostgreSQL code base for ANY_VALUE using ORDER BY suggests that the behavior is indeed unintentional and should not be relied upon (the code base includes such regression tests for other aggregate functions; e.g., ARRAY_AGG).
